# Conditional Filter for 2 Variables with dplyr filter

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am working with some time series (pupil dilation) data and want to filter different time ranges (`Time`) based on a different factor variable (`SOA`)

Sample data:

```
library(dplyr)        

Data <- structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("12", "14", 
        "15", "16", "18", "20", "21", "22", "23", "28", "29", "30", "33", 
        "36", "37", "38", "40", "42", "43", "44"), class = "factor"), 
        SOA = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
        2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
        1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Long SOA", "Short SOA"
        ), class = "factor"), Time = c(-66.68, -66.68, -66.68, -66.68, 
        -33.34, -33.34, -33.34, -33.34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33.34, 33.34, 
        33.34, 33.34, 66.68, 66.68, 66.68, 66.68, 100.02, 100.02, 
        100.02, 100.02, 133.36, 133.36, 133.36, 133.36, 166.7, 166.7, 
        166.7, 166.7), Pcent_Chng = c(0.14391, 0.076759, -0.022377, 
        0.038111, 0.21093, 0.11448, -0.0047064, 0.078232, 0.27924, 
        0.1527, -0.0085276, 0.12385, 0.38328, 0.21299, 0.01988, 0.15626, 
        0.47471, 0.25357, 0.050318, 0.20517, 0.58012, 0.2888, 0.080629, 
        0.20616, 0.65861, 0.33622, 0.12892, 0.20832, 0.75277, 0.38181, 
        0.17921, 0.21789)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -32L), .Names = c("Subject", "SOA", "Time", "Pcent_Chng"))
```

I want to average over a different `Time` period for `SOA = "Short"` than for `SOA = "Long"`.

I've tried these for the `Type = "Word"` (`filter` before and after `group_by`):

```
Data %>% 
filter(Time[SOA = "Short SOA"] >= 0 & Time[SOA = "Short SOA"] <= 100,
       Time[SOA = "Long SOA"] >= 0 & Time[SOA = "Long SOA"] <= 150) %>%
group_by(Subject,SOA) %>%
summarize(Word_Avg_Pcent = mean(Pcent_Chng,na.rm=TRUE))
```

and

```
Data %>% 
group_by(Subject,SOA) %>%
filter(Time[SOA = "Short SOA"] >= 0 & Time[SOA = "Short SOA"] <= 100,
       Time[SOA = "Long SOA"] >= 0 & Time[SOA = "Long SOA"] <= 150) %>%
summarize(Word_Avg_Pcent = mean(Pcent_Chng,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Both result in empty data frames; the columns are there, but no data. If I don't use the second filter, I get a full data frame.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want using pipes and filter in a dplyr chain?

Comment: I see in your 2nd filter you use a comma. This is interpreted as `&`. Any chance you wanted "or"?

Comment: Please make a minimal example. If your question is about filtering, we don't need to see your several steps of variable formatting. Some guidance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250 Also, best to make it properly reproducible, not relying on external links that you or pastebin could break at any time.

Comment: From the documentation, it looks like filter takes multiple arguments, separated by a comma. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: The comma translates so that filter(x,y) is equivalent to filter(x & y) but you want filter(x | y).

Comment: It is but comma will be interpreted as `&`. If you want each one of the conditions to be true use `|` instead of comma. Check the last example here `?dplyr::filter`.

Comment: If I change the comma to a `|`, I still get an empty data frame. Is there a way to separate multiple arguments by "or" (`|`) ?

Comment: After you change that you also have to use parentheses to group your `&`s. Something like `( condition & condition ) | ( condition & condition )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, you need to OR `|` the two AND `&` conditions you are looking for.

Your filter is this:

```
filter(Time[SOA = "Short SOA"] >= 0 & Time[SOA = "Short SOA"] <= 1200, 
       Time[SOA = "Long SOA"] >= 0 & Time[SOA = "Long SOA"] <= 3000)
```

Which has statements that don't evaluate to a logical (e.g. SOA = "Short SOA").  What you need to do is be more explicit.

You want to filter to values where SOA is equivalent to "Short SOA" and have time values between 0 and 1200 or where SOA is equivalent to "Long SOA" and have time values between 0 and 3000.

```
SOA == "Short SOA" and 0 <= Time <= 1200 OR SOA == "Long SOA" and 0 <= Time <= 1200
```

You can use `between` from `dplyr` for the Time conditions.

This implemented is:

```
library(tidyverse)

Data <- eval(parse(file("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VTWCVgCA")))

Data %>% 
  gather(Sample, Prop_Chng, X.8:X100) %>%
  mutate(Sample = gsub("[.]","-", Sample)) %>%
  mutate(Sample = as.numeric(gsub("X","", Sample))) %>%
  mutate(Time = Sample*33.34) %>%
  mutate(Pcent_Chng = Prop_Chng*100) %>%
  filter(Type == "Word") %>% 
  filter((SOA == "Short SOA" & between(Time, 0, 1200)) |  (SOA == "Long SOA" & between(Time, 0, 3000))) %>% 
  group_by(Subject, NsCond,Close,SOA) %>%
  summarize(Word_Avg_Pcent = mean(Pcent_Chng,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I wasn't aware of  `between`